# htaccess RewriteEngine URI allowing multiple slashes

Tags: .htaccess

In my site when i go to `mysite.com/account` or `mysite.com////////account` the output is the same.
How can I avoid multiple slashes to be parsed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only place where that is visible within mod_rewrite is in `%{THE_REQUEST}`. It depends on what you want to do what kind of rule you need. If you want to display a 404-error, you can do this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ [/]{2,}
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
```

It probably makes more sense to simply redirect to the place with just one slash:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ [/]{2,}
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [R]
```

See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for more information about mod_rewrite.